# How to get the id of the user out of jwt token in .net core or how to return a value from a custom authorization attribute?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I create my token in the following way

```
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "tada")
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var encryptedtoken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

And now i would like to simply get the users id from my authorize attribute and put it in the context somehow?
I know i can decode the token like so

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "tada")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization][0];
            var tokenArray = token.Split(" ");
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(tokenArray[1]) as JwtSecurityToken;
            return Ok(tokenS.Payload.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Key == "unique_name").Value);
        }
```

But how do i reuse this code in a more clever way can i create my own authorization attribute that will store it in the context if there is no way, how do i create a singleton/scoped/transient service?

here's how i configure jwt

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CatstagramDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CatstagramDbContext>();
            var applicationSettingConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(applicationSettingConfiguration);

            var appSettings = applicationSettingConfiguration.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                
            });
            app.ApplyMigrations();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function to get any token claim value

```
public static string GetClaimValue(HttpContext httpContext, string valueType)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueType)) return null;
            var identity = httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var valueObj = identity == null ? null : identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == valueType);
            return valueObj==null? null:valueObj.Value;
        }
```

you can use it like this

```
var name = GetClaimValue(HttpContext, "unique_name");
```

Comment: with me its empty i've added my startup now

Comment: @noonecious It means that your autorization is not working.  Pls add full startup code.

Comment: added the startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

When the authentication middleware authenticates the request, it populates `HttpContext.User` property with a `ClaimsPrincipal` that holds the claims for the current user.

`ClaimsPrincipal` class has an extension method in `System.Security.Claims` in namespace called `FindFirstValue`.

```cs
User.FindFirstValue("unique_name");
```

gives you the value for the first `unique_name` claim.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2be49d930a5fb53e781abd175c3b2a8f8b7827d4/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PrincipalExtensions.cs

Comment: with me its empty i've added my startup now

Comment: Do you have `app.UseAuthentication` between `app.UseRouting` and `app.UseEndpoints`?